# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY two unique fields do not insert

Tags: php, mysql

I got this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `set_indice_cuestionarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cuestionario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `hora` time NOT NULL,
  `aplico` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tienda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tienda` (`tienda`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cuestionario` (`cuestionario`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And this is my SQL sentence:

> `$sql_indice = "INSERT INTO set_indice_cuestionarios (cuestionario, fecha, hora, aplico, cliente, tienda) values('$cuestionario','$fecha','$hora','$aplico','$cliente','$tienda') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cuestionario = '$cuestionario', fecha = '$fecha', hora = '$hora', aplico = '$aplico', cliente = '$cliente', status = 0";`

I want to Update a row if $tienda = tienda and $cuestionario = cuestionario and to Insert a new one if the any of the values doesn't match.

The Update is happening when both values match but when I only change $cuestionario it Updates the table, instead of inserting a new record, and when I only change $tienda it does the Insert. I have no idea what I' am doing wrong. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe you are looking for a combined unique key -> `UNIQUE KEY (\`tienda\`,\`cuestionario\`)`. This way it will update when both match, else it will input new.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your insert will probably blow up anyways. you've got a duplicate key on cuestionario, and your on update simply tries to update the field with the value that could have caused the duplicate violation in the first place. e.g you're basically telling mysql "stop punching me in the head by punching me in the head some more".